# Extending library classes with own methods in Delphi pascal

Tags: delphi, methods, extends, tstringgrid

I was wondering if there is a way to add custom method to already existing/included class component in *Delphi Pascal*.

I would like to use this to rotate *StringGrid* like this:

```
StringGridn.rotate(angle);
```

instead of:

```
rotate(StringGridn, angle);
```

Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use helpers like in example below, see [Class and Record Helpers (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)).

```
type  
  TStringGridHelper = class helper for TStringGrid
    procedure Rotate(Angle: Single);
  end;

procedure TStringGridHelper.Rotate(Angle: Single);
begin
  { your implementation }
  Rotate(Self, Angle);  
end;
```

and then just call

```
StringGridn.Rotate(Angle);
```